# echo PHP variable outside loop

Tags: php, loops

I'm using the Simple Fields plugin for a custom WordPress theme. I have the code below to create a dropdown for a size selector, pulling from the options that the admin has created:

```
<select>
<?php if($sizetotal > 0 && $sizes[0] != 0){?>
<?php for($x = 0; $x < $sizetotal; $x++){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $sizes[$x]; ?>"><?php echo $sizes[$x]; ?></option>
<?php }?>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

This is working fine, but I'm wondering how I can echo $sizes[$x]; again, outside this loop so that it reflects what the user chose (in a form, for example).

Very new to PHP, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should put the name to the `<select>` tag. Ex:

   ```
   <select name="sizeSelector">
   ```
2. You can only see the user's chosen value after user submit the form. To read the value use:

   ```
   echo $_POST['sizeSelector']
   ```

   or

   ```
   echo $_GET['sizeSelector']
   ```

   $_GET or $_POST is depends on the method of your form.

The final code shoul be like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sizeSelector'])){
  echo "<div>User chosed the {$_POST['sizeSelector']} size.</div>";
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="sizeSelector">
   <?php if($sizetotal > 0 && $sizes[0] != 0) {
     for($x = 0; $x < $sizetotal; $x++) {
   ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $sizes[$x]; ?>"><?php echo $sizes[$x]; ?></option>
   <?php }
   } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ever having wordpress or this plugin, a google search returns this within 5 seconds:

```
<?php
  // Get the saved value for a field called "video"
  $video_url = simple_fields_value('video');
?>
```

Comment: @blicht454: Your question was "what the user chose". And that's exactly what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to use the value when the user submit the form using the following

```
<?php
     Echo $_POST["optionName"];
?>
```

Assuming the method on your form. All form sent using post method values are stored in a super global variable called $_POST. So you can easily retrieve your value from that array using the element name. You should have the name within the  element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Using JQuery like this

For single select dom elements, to get the currently selected value:

```
var selected = $('#dropDownId').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
var selected = $('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

Or

```
var selected = $("#dropDownId option:selected").text();
```

Then to view the value

```
alert(select);
```

to know more  visit :http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get the value of the selected option to display it elsewhere in your page. In this case you can use javacsript instead :

```
<select onChange="displaySelectedValue(this);">
...
</select>

<script>
function displaySelectedValue(select){
alert(select[select.selectedIndex].value);
};
</script>
```